# Check if argument is not Integer

Tags: shell, integer, arguments

This checks if argument is an integer in Bourne Shell Script:

```
if [[ $3 =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] && ((  $3 >= 1 ))
```

How do I check if argument is not an integer (can consist of integers and alphabets)?
So, I guess it's just the complement of above, but I'm not sure how to change it.
Where can I find info on what these symbol mean?:
=~ ^ + $ &

Answer (score 3):

You can use [De Morgan's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) to negate that if condition check as follows:

```
if [[ ! $3 =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] || ((  $3 < 1 ))
```

- The `!` symbol inside `[[...]]` means negation.
- `$3 < 1` is the negation of `$3 >= 1`

The `=~` operator allows use of Regular Expression in an if statement.

The `&&` used here means "Logical AND"

The rest of the symbols `^ + $` are for [Regular Expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), which is a topic deserving more reading than I can provide in this answer, but in short:

- `^`: match start of line
- `+`: match one or more (in this context it matches one or more digits)
- `$`: match end of line
- Together, `^[0-9]+$` means: Only match a string of nothing but digits.